# Python- Converting tuple to list of multiple lists by index

Tags: python

I have a list of tuples that looks like this:

```
x = [(1, 6), (2, 7), (3, 8), (4, 9), (5, 10)]
```

What is the most pythonic and efficient way to convert into a list of 2 lists where each list respectively has all values of a specific index? Like so:

```
y = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]]
```

Is it possible to do this without a loop?

Comment: with pure python, I'd assume you would only achieve this via list comprehension, which is also looping. importing `numpy as np` you couls just do `np.array(x)` (which of course loops internally, too, but hopefully in the fastest way.)

Comment: numpy is also looping @SpghttCd

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look ma, no loops.

```
>>> list(map(list, zip(*x)))
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]]
```

Comment: @IljaEverilä yeah thanks. Just wanted to answer since the other answer was so obviously wrong

Answer (score 3):

Here you go without a loop (at least informally)

```
[[ele[0] for ele in x]] + [[ele[1] for ele in x]]
```

You have to loop over the elements. There's no other way in python or in any other langauge.

Comment: I see two loops there

Comment: Doesn't matter, it can be O(whatever you like) but it has more loops than OP asked for (which was none)